# Substitutes for non-marriage

Tags: rituals, marriage, anscestors

I don't wanna marry, but I also don't wanna make my ancestors descend from their Loka to the Earth again, which makes me very very sad. Is there a ritual I can do to ensure this doesn't happen without me marrying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Ekadshi fasts. Some of them liberate so many ancestors.